# Load gif on UIImage by Kingfisher

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller, kingfisher

I want to load a gif image on a UIImage using JSQMessageView in cell. I can not access any UIImageView so I did this to change media view. But, the images do not animate. Is it possible to do what I want?

Here is my code:

```
let urlString = Helpers.getUrlFromGiphyText(text: message.body!)
if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
  KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: url, options: 
  [.processor(DefaultImageProcessor.default), 
  .cacheSerializer(FormatIndicatedCacheSerializer.gif)], 
  progressBlock: 
  { receivedSize, totalSize in
  print("(indexPath.row + 1): (receivedSize)/(totalSize)")
  }, completionHandler: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
  if let gifImage = image {
   let mediaItem = JSQPhotoMediaItem(image: gifImage)
   cell.mediaView = mediaItem?.mediaView()
  }
})
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this media fetcher method for my app, and it works fine with gif files.

**NOTE:** Just notice that I use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5)` after the kingfisher manager downloads each file, since without the delay - the gifs don't play at the first download. 
I wrecked my mind on this one. I figure this is probably some cache syncing issue of Kingfisher.

```
mediaFetcher.downloadGifFile(url) { imageUrl in
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        // Use whatever u want to load the gif file
    }
}

class MediaFetcher {
    func downloadGifFile(_ url: URL, completion: @escaping (_ imageURL: URL) -> () = { (imageURL) in} ) {
        KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: url, options: .none, progressBlock: nil) { (image, error, cacheType, imageUrl) in
            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }
            guard let imageUrl = imageUrl else {
                return
            }
            completion(imageUrl)
        }
    }
}
```